# Trying to Detect Characters to determine if Page Should Reload, or not. (Safari Extension)

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

Just so everyone knows, I'm relatively new to JavaScript, (and I've been trying to do things in pure JS rather than using jQuery, etc.). At a place I contract for, we have an Exchange server, I use the webmail client.

To prevent it from timing me out when there isn't any activity, I started putting together a Safari Extension since I could inject JS into a page using one. And I thought it would be a good exercise since I'm learning JS from scratch.

Well, that part of it works, except for when you're replying, or sending a new email, so I tried adding in the second bit of code to prevent that, but it still refreshes. I can't figure out why. I would appreciate any help! I am also going to have to add in rules for if I'm replying, or replying all, but I think if I can get this working, I can get those going to.

So here's my code:

```
if (location.host === "mail.exmx.net") {
    /* The Domain is https://mail.exmx.net/owa/?ae=Folder&t=IPF.Note */

    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload( );
    }, 30000 /* 30 Seconds used just as a test to speed up waiting time*/ );
}

else (location.href.indexOf("?ae=Item&t=IPM.Note&a=New") != -1) {
    /* my attempt at using a static part of the string that's in the location bar when a new email is created */
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: Where's the second part, is that the else statement? You can catch keystrokes and mouse gestures on the entire document and restart the timeout (clear and create again)

Comment: yeah, it is. Like I said, I'd say a little more than beginner level probably, so I still miss/forget things in the syntax...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wonky. Instead of `else`, you need `else if`.

Of course, you could set the timer only if both conditions are set (instead of setting the timer, then clearing it):

```
if (location.host == "mail.exmx.net" && location.href.indexOf("?ae=Item&t=IPM.Note&a=New") == -1) {

    /* The Domain is https://mail.exmx.net/owa/?ae=Folder&t=IPF.Note */

    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload( );
    }, 30000 /* 30 Seconds used just as a test to speed up waiting time*/ );
}
```